# Strings aren’t objects

Tags: string, swift

According to this post: http://roadfiresoftware.com/2014/07/swift-strings-arent-objects/ 
string aren't object in swift. So we cannot use "AnyObject" for string, and we should use the type "Any" instead.

But when I'm assign string into AnyObject it is working.

For example:

```
let str:String = "myString"
let things: [AnyObject] = ["hello",str, 3]


for item in things
{
    println(item)
}
```

output:

```
hello
myString
3
```

What am i missing ?

Comment: Explained here, in my new Swift tutorial: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_anyobject

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's correct saying that a `String` is a value type and not a reference type. However to maintain compatibility with existing API, Swift provides implicit and automatic bridging between Swift's `String` and Foundation's `NSString`, which is a reference type.

So when a swift string is cast to `AnyObject`, it is automatically bridged to `NSString`.

Note that also swift arrays, dictionary and number types have bridged counterparts (respectively `NSArray`, `NSDictionary` and `NSNumber`)

Comment: I would just add: this requires the actual presence of Foundation framework. You are importing Foundation (or UIKit). If you delete that `import`, you won't be able to turn a String into an AnyObject any more - because now it is just a String (there is no NSString to bridge to)!